# Extract 1 page from a password protected PDF

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a (large) PDF file generated by a payroll system. Because of sensitive data, this file is protected with a password.
I would like to extract one page of file and have this page in a separate PDF file.

I tried to Preview, but it is not capable of doing this.

To be more precise, I made an experiment such as I created a 2 pages password protected file on my Mac, I used Preview and I could successfully extract one single page.
But the same operation does not work with the file I have.

Would somebody know why?
Does Preview has some limitations in reading/handling PDFs?

By chance, if anybody would know how to deal with such a "special" PDF file, it would be great to share.

Best,

Comment: tools -> show inspector, change password options here

Comment: Are you authorised to extract a page from the file, or are you asking us to help you circumvent company policies?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways that PDF documents can be protected.

[image]

A password can be required to open the document, but another password - the "Owner" Password can be set in order to restrict the access once opened.

It's likely that your document has restrictions against copying and/or editing the pages, which would prevent you from extracting a page.